# Checked item always appends in the arraylist when added

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm adding the checked item in an arraylist but always appends when i clicked an item. Also when i unchecked it, it also appends in the arraylist. This is the code:

```
List<String> ingList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> onhandIngList = new ArrayList<String>();
ingList.add("one");
ingList.add("two");
intList.add("three");

//displays the arraylist using arrayadapter
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ingList);

if(ingList.size() != 0) {
    listView.setAdapter (arrayAdapter);
}else{
    Toast.makeText (Ingredients.this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
}

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long l) {
       Object clickItemObj = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(index);
       onhandList.add(( String ) clickItemObj);
   }
});
```

I expect the output will be the value of the checked item. But no repetitive outputs.

Comment: change your `List<String> onhandlngList` to: `Set<String> onhandlingList` . More about `Set`: [https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try something like this (inside of onItemClick()):

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
      if(checked.get(index)){
            onhandlist.add(...)
        }
        else{
            onhandList.remove(...)
        }
```